# Regarding LLVM compiling flag "-mlong-calls" for "Other C Flags" in XCode.

Tags: xcode, llvm

What does this flag mean? How will it be used? For which purpose will need to enable this flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [ARM options page for GCC;](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html)

> Tells the compiler to perform function calls by first loading the
>   address of the function into a register and then performing a
>   subroutine call on this register. This switch is needed if the target
>   function lies outside of the 64-megabyte addressing range of the
>   offset-based version of subroutine call instruction.

Basically it means that if your binary is small, you'll likely never have a problem with running the default `-mno-long-calls` and not have to worry about the option.

If the linker gives you the error `Relocation truncated to fit: R_ARM_PC24`, you've hit the limit of the defaults and need to **compile and link** your binary using `-mlong-calls`.

Comment: I see, only related with linker address, no special factor with app performance.